# Duplicating Questions in a userform through the push of a button

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a userform through Execl VBA and on the userform I currently have a frame (ID: Frame1) and within this frame I have a question:

```
 1) How many dogs do you have
```

But the problem is, I want to have a button underneath the question (still within the frame) that will allow me to duplicate the frame and the question within the frame below the existing frame. I have searched high and low for information on this and I can't seem to obtain it from anywhere.

Comment: It sounds like you would want to create a new frame, set its values the same as the existing one and then change its position.

Comment: There is a way to recreate objects on forms with VBA, but I don't believe that you will be able create the object with the same ID info. In that case, all references to the information will still call the original info. Why do you need to recreate the object/question?

Comment: I just want it to save time for the users of my form! I don't want to manually duplicate all my questions either because it would look really amateur. The Id's don't need to be the same when they are duplicated!

Answer (score 0):

One way of creating controls can be found here:

http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HV080006706&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL%2EDEV&Version=14&tl=2&queryid=&respos=1&HelpID=fm20%2Echm2000250

Adding a new Frame control to a Userform:

```
Dim newFrame As Frame
Set newFrame = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1")
'set frame position, caption
newFrame.Caption = "<My next question>"
newFrame.Left = 10
newFrame.Top = 10
'set size the same as Frame1
newFrame.Width = Frame1.Width
newFrame.Height = Frame1.Height
```